# Delete elements of array that end with certain strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I have an array and I need every element that ends with a certain string to be deleted.

```
var arr = ["strawberry", "apple", "blueberry"];
```

I need every element that ends with ***berry*** to be deleted. The array should end up like this:

```
var arr = ["apple"];
```

Comment: Please post your attempts so far and we can try to help you out.

Comment: Welcome to SO! try solving it yourself, then if you face any problem(s), post your code with details! If you need a start for this problem, look at ways to iterate arrays and array related functions in javaScript.

Answer (score 5):

You can user [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new, filtered array:

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function(arrayElement){
    return arrayElement.indexOf("berry") != arrayElement.length - "berry".length;
});
```

From the docs:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

So, the provided callback should return `true` to project the element into the output array, or `false` to omit it. How you might implement the test is down to you. The test I provide is somewhat naive.

Comment: Not op, but could you explain how the code works as opposed to just giving the answer? It would benefit future visitors as well

Answer (score 4):

To find items that ends with something we use `something$` (the `$` indicates the end of string or end of line). If we negate this `regex` expression we can find items that not ending with that string.
On other hand, arrays in javascript have a `filter` function that filters the array items based on a filtering function. By combining this two we can create a new array just containing what we want.

```js
 
var arr = ["strawberry", "apple", "blueberry"];      
var endsWith = "berry"
var regx = new RegExp(endsWith+"$");
var result = arr.filter(function(item){return !regx.test(item);})
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `Array.prototype.filter()` combined with `String.prototype.endsWith()`:

```js
// Declaring array of fruits
let arr = ['strawberry', 'apple', 'blueberry'];

// Filtering elements that are not ending with 'berry'
let filtered = arr.filter(fruit => !fruit.endsWith('berry'));

console.log(filtered);
// ['apple']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var fruits = ["strawberry", "apple", "blueberry"];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
var a = fruits[i].indexOf("berry") > -1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

Comment: You can indent four spaces to create code blocks, instead of using backticks on each line (I'm assuming) Just FYI

Comment: What does your answer do??  Your code actually prints/assigns true/false values to `a`. Where do you see an element with id "demo" in the problem? Sorry but your answer is not making much sense wrt to the problem. Perhaps you wanted to do something like, `var fruits = ["strawberry", "apple", "blueberry"];

for(var i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
    if(fruits[i].indexOf("berry") > -1){
    delete fruits[i];
    }
}`.  I edited the answer, but was not accepted. P.S. I didn do that minus.